# How to push the array inside the $args['date_query'] in WordPress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, date

I'm getting the $years as input from the user. It will have one year value or multiple based on that I've to add to $args query how to add that below is my code. Which returns only 1st element years post.

```
if ( !empty($years) ) {
    foreach($years as $year):
        $args['date_query'] = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array( 'year' => $year),
        );
    endforeach;
}
```

$years will have the values like

```
$years = array(2022,2023);
```

Expected output should be

```
$args['date_query'] = array( 
    'relation' => 'OR', 
     array( 'year' => 2022), 
     array( 'year' => 2023), 
);
```

Comment: I can understand that the posted code doesn't work as expected since you're currently overwriting `$args['date_query']` on every iteration. Other than that, like how you should change it depends on what the expected result from the above code is, which you haven't shared. Nor have you shared what `$years` contains

Comment: In the $args['date_query'] i want to append array( 'year' => 2023) this array. If I found the multiple values in $years.

Comment: please edit your question, to add more information

Comment: Initialize with `$args['date_query'] = ['relation' => 'OR'];` before the loop, and inside the loop add further elements, `$args['date_query'][] = ['year' => $year];` (`[...]` is just a shorter way to write `array(...)`.)